# Can Firefox's show the upload status of a file?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

When you upload a picture somewhere, while using chrome, you can see the status bar actually shows the "status" of the upload, the percentage of the upload completed. Is there any way Firefox's status bar can show this upload status?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

googled for this and found this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uploadprogress/

Comment: It looks nice, but i tried it before and it wasn't working for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: It actually shows some uploads when i am surfing. But when i upload a file it doesnt seem to show that anything is uploaded

Comment: I test it just now and worked. You have to add the button from options->personalize. It opens a dialog wich is shown on every TAB you open, so you can surf another pages while still uploading something. I think the upload progress is a big missing feature of Firefox but this addon is good enough :)

Comment: Doesn't work on newer versions of FF, unfortunately.